# it's possible? input text 2 place textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

it's possible?
when write text in input text can send (2 place textarea)
and open 2 Tab on browser.(Page1.html and Page2.html)

Page1.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendtext(){
       /*Input TimeLineText to textarea in page 1 on browser*/
       document.textarea.textarea_in_page1=input.getElementById('TimeLineText');
       /*Input TimeLineText to textarea in page 2 on browser*/
       document.textarea.textarea_in_page2=input.getElementById('TimeLineText');
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="TimeLineText" 
name="text" value="TimeLineText" onkeyup="sendtext();" />
<textarea id="textarea_in_page1"> TimeLineText </textarea>
```

Page2.html

```
<textarea id="textarea_in_page2"> TimeLineText </textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible If you are using HTML5. Check out localStorage. It is implemented in all the modern browsers.

It permanently stores strings across all tabs within the same domain.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/